# search contains string in array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a string like this `search = 'hello'` and I need check all array to see if any contains `hello`.
For example:

```
"hello" == "123hello123" | true
"hello" == "aasdasdasd123hello123" | true
"hello" == "123123hello" | true
```

I need something like search for my code

`list_all_files_in_google_drive` - it my all file name array

`filename` - name file, which need to check if exist in google drive or not

```
if not any(file['title'] == filename for file in list_all_files_in_google_drive):
   print('file not exist')
```

my code doesn't work because it works like this:

```
"hello" == "123hello123" | false
"hello" == "aasdasdasd123hello123" | false
"hello" == "123123hello" | false
"hello" == "hello" | true
```

and I need it to work like this:

```
"hello" == "123hello123" | true
"hello" == "aasdasdasd123hello123" | true
"hello" == "123123hello" | true
"hello" == "hello" | true
```

**UPD:**

I checked operator `in` and it does not output `true`

```
filename = 'hello'
list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']
if filename in list:
    print('true')
```

Comment: try "hello" in "123hello123"

Comment: But you've replaced the whole loop with `in`. That's not what Rakesh told you to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go through each string in the list with a simple loop, and check if `'hello'` exists with the pythons membership [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator:

```
lst = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']

for x in lst:
    if 'hello' in x:
        print('true')
```

Which outputs:

```
true
true
true
```

Or if you want to check [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) the strings in `lst` at once:

```
if all('hello' in x for x in lst):
    print('true')
```

Or if you want to check if [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#any) of the strings in `lst` at once:

```
if any('hello' in x for x in lst):
    print('true')
```

Both of which will output:

```
true
```

**Note:** Using `list` as a variable name as shown in your question is not a good idea here, as it shadows the builtin function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list). Also returning a boolean `True` or `False` here is fine, not need to return a string form of these.

Comment: Why not `for l in lst: if 'hello' in l:` The Variable `filename` seems a little redundant....

Comment: @RoadRunner this example work perfetly, i use `if any('hello' in x for x in lst):` but mayby you know why this is false `search_word = Taxi Stockholm  Kostnad för resa 545 kr.pdf`, and list contains `20170906144217_2of3_556944-8102+FAKTURA_luisa@gluehome.com_Taxi Stockholm Kostnad för resa 545 kr.pdf` why it output false?

Answer (score 6):

Replace '==' with **'in'**

```
"hello" in "123hello123"            # RETURNS True
"hello" in "aasdasdasd123hello123"  # RETURNS True
"hello" in "123123hello"            # RETURNS True
"hello" in "hello"                  # RETURNS True
```

Comment: thks for answered, but i try you example and it not work, please see [https://repl.it/repls/MintcreamDarkslategreyAustrianpinscher](https://repl.it/repls/MintcreamDarkslategreyAustrianpinscher)

Comment: Sorry I am unable to open the link you provided. Can you post what you tried in the comments?

Comment: if not any(file['title'] in filename for file in list_all_files_in_google_drive):
   print('file not exist') this is how to use 'in'

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions as shown below:

```
filename = 'hello'
my_list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']

print all([True if filename in _ else False for _ in my_list])

filename = 'hello'
my_list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123helo']

print all([True if filename in _ else False for _ in my_list])
```

**output:**

```
True
False
```

Another solution is to have a own function as follows:

```
def check_filename(filename_string, input_list):
    result = 'true'
    for _ in input_list:
        if filename_string not in _:
            result = 'false'
            break
    return result

filename = 'hello'
my_list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']

print(check_filename(filename_string=filename, input_list=my_list))

filename = 'hello'
my_list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123ho123', '123123hello']

print(check_filename(filename_string=filename, input_list=my_list))
```

**output:**

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one dude :

```
filename = 'hello'
list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']
if (filename.find(file) for file in list):
      print('true')
```

Comment: `filename = '555'
list = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello']
if (filename.find(file) for file in list):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')` it always output `true`

Comment: then change filename.find(file) to filename in file and try

Answer (score 0):

'in' operator is good solution , You can also try regex :

```
import re
pattern=r'hello'
lst = ['123hello123', 'aasdasdasd123hello123', '123123hello','nothing']
for i in lst:
    if re.search(pattern,i):
        print("string : {} result : {} ".format(i,True))
    else:
        print("string : {} result : {} ".format(i,False))
```

output:

```
string : 123hello123 result : True 
string : aasdasdasd123hello123 result : True 
string : 123123hello result : True 
string : nothing result : False
```